# Search for multiple words in a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, search

I have a text transcripts (string) column in a table in SQL Server and I need to identify if any of the records contains a social security number (no digits in this column, only text, so I need to spell out the digits). In other words I need to check if any of the strings contains any combination of nine digits from the ten possible digits (one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, zero). I may be okay with identifying a combination of any four digits (last four of the social security number).

I tried `Like '%one%' or Like '%two%'` and so on, but that only identifies single words. I need to find at least any four in any consequence in the same string.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aggregated `EXISTS` with a constructed table of words

```sql
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM (VALUES
        ('zero'),
        ('one'),
        ('two'),
        ('three'),
        ('four'),
        ('five'),
        ('six'),
        ('seven'),
        ('eight'),
        ('nine')
    ) v(word)
    WHERE t.YourColumn LIKE '%' + v.word + '%'
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4
);
```

You could change `>= 4` to `= 9` to get an exact match on the number of words